# Как правильно следить за файлом?

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток.
Суть вопроса: нужно мониторить изменения в файле, а точнее то, когда в него добавляются новые строки.
Понятно, что нужно использовать FileSystemWatch, StreamReader, но суть в том, что при сохранении файла почему-то дважды вызывается Changed событие у FileSystemWatch, а чтение из файла почему-то дает сначала пустую строку, а потом новые строки из файла.
Код:

```
static void Main()
{
  var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
  var file = Path.Combine(path, "1.txt");

  var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(path, "1.txt");
  fsw.Changed += Sfw_Changed;
  fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
  fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

  FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite); //открываем для чтения, но не блокируем файл.
  sr = new StreamReader(fs);
  sr.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End); //Прыгаем в конец, старые данные нам не интересны.

  AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
  autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

```
private static void Sfw_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Changed)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e.ChangeType);

    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
    }
  }
}
```

Что обычно вижу в консоли: (первая строка пустая, дальше - новые данные из файла)
[image: консоль]

Главные вопросы:

1. Почему 2 раза вызывается событие, если я сохраняю файл 1 раз;
2. От куда он берет пустую строку?

Comment: 1. Наверно потому, что вы останавливаетесь в конце конкретной строки, а новая строка у вас начинается с `\r\nНовый текст`. Вот просто создайте текстовый документ, в котором будет несколько строк, а затем прочитайте его через `File.ReadAllText()`, увидите нечто такое `"1\r\n2\r\n3"`, вот грубо говоря вы написали 1, все ок, нажали enter чтоб перейти на новую строку, написали 2, сохранили, в текстовик в итоге добавится `\r\n2`, вот вам и пустая строка. Тут либо меняйте `Console.WriteLine()` на `Console.Write()`, либо пишите в файл так, чтоб в конце всегда была пустая строка. 2. Не воспроизводится

Comment: Да, вы правы, если в конце добавлять строку, то всё становится так, как должно быть. Оформите ответов, помечу его ответом.

Comment: Если бы я хотел, то наверно уже бы это все было в виде ответа) Так что, можете оформлять сами, указав там все, что вы поняли.

Comment: Понял, благодарю :)

Comment: Я ведь выше написал "Не воспроизводится". То есть, у меня ваш код отрабатывает без проблем, одно событие на 1 сохранение. Правил файл простым блокнотом. Может у вас там другой софт вмешивается в работу, редактор сохраняет по несколько раз, или может это вовсе, такое поведение на старых .NET (у себя проверял на .NET 6), не знаю, лишь догадки.

Comment: Хм, оказалось проще всё, Notepad++ почему-то делает такое. Через системный блокнот всё ок. Спасибо, сейчас оформлю ответ.

Answer (score 0):

За решение спасибо @EvgeniyZ, решение с пустой строкой: нужно после добавления всех новых строк в файле добавить новую строку (пустую);
Решение двойным вызовом - особенность Notepad++, через системный блокнот вызывается один раз.

Comment: Тут возможно дело в типе открытия дескриптора к файлу (открыть для чтения или открыть для сохранения) текстовым редактором. И возможно ещё в отслеживании открытий для атрибута "Открыт" (когда был открыт) со стороны операционной системы. Но в вашем случае скорее всего первое.